# Switch a static class to a regular one with constructor injection or keep it static with method injection for enhancements?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection

I encountered a code modification that added a dependency to static classes, with the dependency being passed through method injection. Is it advisable to opt for constructor injection instead of method injection? Are there any pitfalls to be aware of when choosing between the two approaches?

## Initial version

```
public class Mapper {
private final A a;

public K getConstraint(A a){
 final boolean bool = isFeasible(ex);
 ...
 a.something();
 }
}

public final class Util {

  public static boolean isFeasible(String ex) {
    return ex.equals(something);

  }
}
```

## Version 1: Keep it static and use method injection

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class Mapper {
private final A a;
private final Order order;

public Map<C,D> getConstraint(A a, Order order){
 final boolean bool = isFeasible(ex, order);
 ...
 a.something();
 }
}

public final class Util {

  public static boolean isFeasible(String ex, Order order) {
   if (X) {
    return ex.equals(something);
   }
   return order.something();
  }
}
```

## Version 2: Make it regular class and use constructor injection

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class Mapper {
  private final A a;

  public Map<C,D> getConstraint(){
  final boolean bool = isFeasible(ex);
  ...
  a.something();
 }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class Util {
  private final Order order;

  public boolean isFeasible(String ex) {
   if (X) {
    return ex.equals(something);
   }
   return order.something();

 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general observation, [Dependency Injection is just passing arguments](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/dependency-injection-is-passing-an-argument), so annotations shouldn't be required.

The choice, then, is whether to pass arguments via constructors or as method arguments.

Is there are way to choose between one or the other?

When the classes involved are concrete classes that are not part of any polymorphic API (i.e. they neither inherit from a base class nor implement an interface), there's not much of a difference.

Things change if the class that needs the dependency implements a polymorphic API. In that case, you may not be able to change method signatures, because they're already given (by base class or interface). Furthermore, client code may not have access to the dependency; often, the point of Dependency Injection is that you decouple object composition from object interaction.

In those cases (which are the most frequent) you *can't* pass dependencies via methods, as this would break contracts (or violate the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)). By elimination, then, you'll have to pass dependencies via the constructor.

All that said, beware of [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) and [sequential coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling). If you pass a dependency as a method argument, it shouldn't also be a class field.